# Setting timeouts for grpc functions in node js

Tags: node.js, grpc

Trying to create a timeout for grpc connection in the event that the server grpc implementation doesn't specify a callback function, however it seems that no matter what is specified in the options (new Date().getSeconds()+5) the client doesn't terminate the connection

```
    function hello (call, callback) {
        console.log(call.request.message)
    }
    server.addService(client.Hello.service, {hello: hello});
    server.bind('localhost:50051', grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure());
    server.start();
    grpcClient = new client.Hello('localhost:50051',
        grpc.credentials.createInsecure(),{deadline: new Date().getSeconds()+5}); //


    grpcClient.hello({message: "abc"}, function(err, response) {
        console.log(response) // doesn't reach here because function hello doesn't callback
    })
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also set rpc deadline as:

```
function getRPCDeadline(rpcType) {

    timeAllowed = 5000
    switch(rpcType) {

        case 1:
            timeAllowed = 5000  // LIGHT RPC
            break

        case 2 :
            timeAllowed = 7000  // HEAVY RPC
            break

        default :
            console.log("Invalid RPC Type: Using Default Timeout")

    }

    return new Date( Date.now() + timeAllowed )

}
```

And then use this function while calling any rpc:

```
var deadline = getRPCDeadline(1)

grpcClient.hello({message: "abc"},{deadline: deadline}, function(err, response) {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(response)
});
```

Comment: This one is the correct answer. Please use call options to specify deadlines. The "accepted answer" is a kludge, and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Are there equivalent timeouts on the server side? That is can the server set a deadline for the client to send it data on a client stream?

Answer (score 5):

Ok seems like got it working with the below code:

```
var timeout_in_seconds = 5
var timeout = new Date().setSeconds(new Date().getSeconds() + timeout_in_seconds)

grpcClient.hello({message: "abc"},{deadline: timeout}, function(err, response) {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(response)
});
```

Comment: FYI: gRPC doesn't use "timeouts" (which are relative, like 5 seconds), but instead uses "deadlines" (which are absolute points in time).  This may be why you had trouble finding it.

Comment: FYI2: you can also do `{deadline: Date.now() + timeoutMilliseconds}`

Answer (score 0):

https://grpc.io/docs/guides/concepts.html#cancelling-rpcs

Deadlines/Timeouts

> gRPC allows clients to specify how long they are willing to wait for
>   an RPC to complete before the RPC is terminated with the error
>   DEADLINE_EXCEEDED. On the server side, the server can query to see if
>   a particular RPC has timed out, or how much time is left to complete
>   the RPC.
>
> How the deadline or timeout is specified varies from language to
>   language - for example, not all languages have a default deadline,
>   some language APIs work in terms of a deadline (a fixed point in
>   time), and some language APIs work in terms of timeouts (durations of
>   time).